# Equivalent 'cubic' method for interp3 MATLAB in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy, code-translation

I am very frustrated because I cannot find a solution: I have to do a 3D interpolation in python using a cubic method. The MATLAB equivalent is

```
Vi = interp3(x,y,z,V,xi,yi,zi,'cubic')
```

where

> x, y, z are 3D arrays in [N x N x N]
>
> V is a 3D array in [N x N x N]
>
> xi, yi, zi are 1D arrays [1 x M]

in my case N=69 and M=120000

Is it possible translate that code from MATLAB to python efficiently?

I tried to use [`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy-interpolate-regulargridinterpolator) but it does not seem to solve my problem, because of the methods implemented and the dimensions of the arrays allowed.

Comment: Did you already look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata ?

Comment: @Dietrich The problem of  `scipy.interpolate.griddata` that I can do maximum a 2-D cubic interpolation. Even if I flat the vectors and I use just x [ N**3 X 1] and xi [M x 1] using a 1-D cubic interpolation, (that does not fit my solution) I get a MemoryError